Switching between routes using next/navigation Link re-render routes pages

I use Next js with App router.
My app looks like this:
enter image description here
My navigation bar with tabs stays in the main layout:
enter image description here
Each tab represents a different route and different page:
enter image description here

PROBLEM: when I e.g. type something in the Users page and then switch a tab and return to my Users tab - Users components re-render. I need it to not change during switching tabs. Later on, there could be many tabs opened and I don't want to re-render them each time a tab is changing - each route page could be very complex inside and I can't imagine storing every user movement in e.g. Redux and recreating the whole page every time user switch the tab...
Could you please help me with it?
I tried to wrap the Users component with React.memo() but it does not work..
I expect not re-render components when switching tabs
